# PHP Simple HTML DOM parser - parsing nested elements

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I've been playing with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser Manual found here http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm and I got success with some tests except this one:

It got nested tables and spans and I would like to parse the outer text of span with class of mynum.

```
<?php

require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

$url = 'http://relumastudio.com/test/target.html';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.21 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1042.0 Safari/535.21");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

$DEBUG = 1;

if($DEBUG){
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load($url);
    echo $html->find('span[class=mynum]',0)->outertext; // I should get 123456
}else{
    echo $result;
}        
curl_close($ch);
```

I thought I could get away with just once call to `echo $html->find('span[class=mynum]',0)->outertext;` to get the text `123456` but I can't.

Any ideas? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: You should post the html with your question rather than the curl code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the url properly first. Then use `->innertext` in this case:

```
$url = 'http://relumastudio.com/test/target.html';
$html = file_get_html($url);
$num = $html->find('span.mynum', 0)->innertext;
echo $num;
```

Comment: for the simple example I had, your solution worked. but if I change the URL link to same structure, it doesn't work anymore. Actually, I make a simple example out of the URL that I want to parse with exact same structure but simplified. Care to see the URL?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63479/discussion-between-reymangana-and-ghost).

Answer (score 0):

You need innertext.

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($url);
echo $html->find('span[class=mynum]',0)->innertext;
```

outertext returns `<span class="mynum">123456</span>`

Comment: @MIvanlsten, I'v tried it but still its returning NULL.

Comment: are you sure you have the 123456 in that span? maybe the spam is empty so obviously no result is returned...

Comment: @AresDraguna Yes. please inspect this url http://relumastudio.com/test/target.html

Comment: what does `$html->find('span[class=mynum]',0)->innertext;` return?